# How do i call function from Cell Renderer - ag grid

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, cellrenderer

i'm using cellrenderer in vue.js, i want to call function from the cell renderer.

attached here my code:

```js
gridColumns() {
  return [{
      headerName: "Actions",
      cellRenderer: 'iconRender',
      width: 140,
      cellRendererParams: (params) => {
        return {
          icon: ['edit', 'delete_forever'],
          color: 'gray'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      headerName: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Artiyfactory Name",
      field: "artifactoryName"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Artifact Type",
      field: "artifactType"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Deployment Action",
      field: "deploymentAction"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Location",
      field: "usage.location"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Destenition On Setup",
      field: "usage.destOnSetup"
    },
  ]
}
},

function iconRender(params) {
  var spanElement = document.createElement("span");
  var textElement = document.createElement("span");
  if (params.value != undefined) {
    textElement.innerHTML = " " + params.value;
    textElement.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
  }
  params.icon.forEach(element => {
    var iconElement = document.createElement("i");
    iconElement.className = "material-icons";
    iconElement.style.color = params.color;
    iconElement.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
    iconElement.innerHTML = element;
    spanElement.appendChild(iconElement);
  });
  spanElement.appendChild(textElement);
  return spanElement;
}
```

I want to call to a function from the icon element, I tried a few way's but nothing work for me.

can you please take a look and tell me how can I do it?

Thank you :)

Comment: you might have lucking binding the function to the attribute when declaring the ColDef like so: `{cellRenderer: this.iconRender.bind(this)}`

Comment: Thank you!, can you tell me what should I write in the iconRender in order to call myfunc()?

Comment: when you pass the column definition to the ag-grid instance, it will have your function bound to `cellrenderer` attribute for that column. So when in its build lifecycle it checks the value at `cellRenderer` it will see your function and fire it then.

Comment: but i don't anderstand how i call the function, I want to call som function when clicking on the icon

Comment: ah - then you need to attach a click handler. GridOptions has a 'onCellClicked' attribute and there you will assign a function.

Comment: i don't want cell click, i want iconclick..., is it possible?

Comment: then you can assign a click handler thru the dom - but may effect perfomance

Comment: what do you mean 'dom' ?

Comment: Document Object Model https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: this could work   params.icon.forEach(element => {
    var iconElement = document.createElement("i");
    iconElement.className = "material-icons"......
    iconElement.addEventListener('click', () => YOUR FUNCTION)
    spanElement.appendChild(iconElement);
  });

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating element via dom. you can create the custome component for cell. in ag-grid when you click on cell it's only capture event of cells click not what inside cell(in your case icon). You can create custome component for cell rendered and you can able to do all things like normal component. Please refer [https://plnkr.co/edit/3nZPzwmGufKGXwvn] i make comments on plunker please refere last column where they have button.